# Snowflake column with triple double-quotes is always flagged as "Invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, select, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Multiple snowflake columns are like this `"""SOME TEXT WITH SPACES"""`

No issue when I'm doing a `SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE`

---

But I can't figure out how to query the columns with double-quotes...

If I do :

`SELECT """SOME TEXT WITH SPACES""" FROM MY_TABLE`

I receive

> SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 7 invalid identifier '""SOME TEXT WITH SPACES""'

I've tried adding other double-quotes but I can't find the right combination...

Comment: How about renaming the columns to something sensible?

Comment: @NickW : It would have been my first choice too but I'm not the only one using this and it's supposed to stay the way it is to keep historical data untouched...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a table when selected from:

```
select * from names;
```

looks likes this:

| NO_QUOTE | also_no_quote | "single_quotes" | """triple_quotes""" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 |

You need to understand how it was created, which is also how it need to be accessed :

- There is the first layer of double quotes to turn off the case    insensitivity.
- Then for each extra layer of wanted double quotes in    the output you have to use two double quotes on both sides.

Thus *tripple quotes* was made and accessed by 7 double quotes:

```
create or replace table names (no_quote int, 
    "also_no_quote" int, 
    """single_quotes""" int, 
    """""""triple_quotes""""""" int);

insert into names values (0,0,1,3);
```

and thus can be accessed by:

```
select no_quote, "also_no_quote", """single_quotes""", """""""triple_quotes""""""" from names;
```

Comment: Perfect ! 7 double-quotes, I gave up at 6 !
Seems strange to create fields with so many, but who am I to judge ? xD

Comment: @R3uK yes, it so crazy, it's almost a hidden prime generator.

Answer (score -1):

You need to select the column name using quotes because column names are case sensitive if they are created in double quotes.

Example

```
create or replace table doublequotes (
  seq int,
  """last_name""" string,
  first_name string
  );




insert into doublequotes values (10, 'abcd', 'efgh');
 
select """last_name""" from doublequotes;
```

o/p: abcd

Please try.